# C++ link time resource "allocation" without defines

Tags: c++, templates, linker, resources, compile-time-type-checking

I'm currently working on a C++ class for an ESP32. I want to implement resource allocation of the resources like: IO-Pins, available RMT channels and so on.
My idea is to do this with some kind of resource handler which checks this at compile time, but I have no good idea nor did I find anything about something like this yet.

To clarify my problem lets have an example of what I mean.
Microcontroller X has IO pins 1-5, each of these can be used by exactly one component.

Components don't know anything from each other an take the pin they should use as a ctor argument.
Now I want to have a class/method/... that checks if the pin, a component needs, is already allocated at compile time.

```
CompA a(5); //works well: 5 is not in use
CompB b(3); //same as before, without the next line it should compile
CompC c(5); //Pin 5 is already in use: does not compile!
```

Im not sure yet how to do so. My best guess (as I can't use defines here: users should be able to use it only by giving a parameter or template argument) is, that it might work with a template function, but I did not find any way of checking which other parameters have been passed to a template method/class yet.

**Edit1**: Parts of the program may be either autogenerated or user defined in a manner, they do not know about other pin usages. The allocation thus is a "security" feature which should disallow erroneous code. This should also forbid it, if the register functions are in different code pathes (even if they might exclude each other)

**Edit2**: I got a response, that compile time is wrong here as components might be compiled separated from another. So the only way to do so seems like a linker error.

Comment: Do you want to use different classes for each component? Just like in your example.

Comment: Yeah. Imagine two complete different components like an LED driver for smart leds and an 1-Wire driver. For some reason which leads to invalid code both components want to use the same hardware pin which obviously shouldn't be possible. As I'm working on an IoT framework which generates code such things might happen. I would like not having broken hardware with runtime errors but compile time errors for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

A silly `C`-style method: you could desperately use `__COUNTER__` as the constructor's argument. This dynamic macro increases itself after each appearance, starting with 0.

I hope there's a better solution.

Comment: Interesting Idea, but wouldn't that mean, that components not only need to be called in the correct order, but also can't use an "random" pin number.
If compA wants to use Pin 3, compB Pin 2 and nobody needs Pin 1 it wouldn't work out.

Comment: @FenBerlind that's a trouble, though you can try to use some "odd" `__COUNTER__` "calls" for skipping certain numbers.

Comment: Even thought this might work in some way, I guess that it wouldn't be a good idea to use it that way as it makes coding more complex (order has to be kept in mind) and might break when using libraries which use `___COUNTER___` for whatsoever.